# Azure DevOps REST API for Test Case Parameters Values

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to call test case parameters values with REST API. Does DevOps have a REST API to call test case parameters?

I found only how to call test case:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases/{testCaseIds}?api-version=5.0
```

From: [Test Case REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20case%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct way to get parameters is to add `fields=Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource` in the URL. Like this:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?fields=Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource&api-version=5.1
```

The Resposne will like this

XML Format:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <xs:schema id='NewDataSet'
        xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
        xmlns:msdata='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata'>
        <xs:element name='NewDataSet' msdata:IsDataSet='true' msdata:Locale=''>
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs = 'unbounded'>
                    <xs:element name='Table1'>
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name='Language' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' />
                                <xs:element name='ItemNo' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' />
                                <xs:element name='Item' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' />
                                xs:element name='User' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' />
                                <xs:element name='Password' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' />
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <Table1>
        <Language>EN</Language>
        <ItemNo>1234</ItemNo>
        <Item>Item1</Item>
        <User>User1</User>
        <Password>Pass1</Password>
    </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciate you share the solution here. You can accept your answer so that others could direct know it is work!

Answer (score 3):

Test Case it's a work item type, so you can use the [Get Work Item Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get the parameters:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.0
```

In the response you will get this in the `fields` section:

```
Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Parameters: "<parameters><param name='test'><value>Shayki</value></param></parameters>"
```

Comment: Hi @Shayki Abramczyk , 

What is the REST API for creating or updating the Azure TestPlan Shared Parameter?

if the REST API available kindly share the reference of request body

Comment: Hi @Balamurugan I really don't know, I didn't touch the Tests section for long time...